# How to set value from firebase into TextFieldForm with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using StreamBuilder to get data from Firestore.
However I have no idea how to set specific data on TextFormField.
I'm trying to use TextEditingController to put text on TextFormField.

I can get document ID for firestore.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String memberID;

  EditPage({Key key, @required this.memberID});

  @override
  _EditPageState createState() => _EditPageState();
}

class _EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {
  TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  void _editMember() {
    Firestore.instance.collection('members').document('cGbVJaL7Ib4S3cKXBQmE').updateData({
      'last_name': lastNameController.text,
    });

    setState(() {
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Update Member'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: new StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('members').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                }
                switch (snapshot.connectionState){
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading...');
                  default:
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget> [
                        Text('${widget.memberID}'),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: lastNameController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            filled: true,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                            labelText: 'Name',
                          ),
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return 'Requierd';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        new GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            print('Register!!');
                            _editMember();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child:
                          new Container(
                            height: 54.00,
                            width: 311.00,
                            child: new Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text('Update'),
                                ]
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffffa031),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27.00),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                }
              }
            ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Would you give me some advice?

Comment: Yep. Use TextEditingController is a right choice. What do you mean with an advice?

Comment: TextEditingController instance is out of scope, when I use in StreamBuilder scope.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? To show how you're using TextEditingConttoller

Comment: Here I uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I realize when TextFormField value is changed, setState caused. My question is how to set value when the page is called first time then set value on TextFormField from Firebase.

Comment: If you want the textformfield to already have data what you can do is use the `initialValue` property and for its value do *snapshot.data.example*

Comment: When I added `initialValue`, an error comes out. with controller does not seem to match.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Did you use the controller as the value? You are not supposed to do that. If so, that is not how it is done, you need to use 'snapshot.data.last_name'(or whatever data you are trying to retrieve)

Comment: I am trying to create instanse `TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();`  Then put value like `lastNameController.text = 'xxxxx'` from firebase.

Comment: Well, you can just do `lastNameController.text = snapshot.data.example`

Comment: I don't know where I should write it. It become out of scope.

Comment: Well, the only place you will be able to access the snaphot.data is under streambuilder. Exactly what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TextEditingController` and update the value of `TextFormField` in `initState` based on Firestore.

```
  // Declare your controller and set the initial value
  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: 'initial value');

  @override
  initState() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('members')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      // Update the TextFormField value here
      firstNameController.text = snapshot.documents.first['something'];
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I guess I will be almost there. In this case, I can only get first data in collection. How can I get from document ID in firebase?

Comment: It was an example. If you want to query only one document by its id, you need to use `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with following code I expected.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("members").document("docID").get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
});
```

Thank you for all of advices.