# How to get specified value from firestore with `DOCUMENT ID` with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm from following issue again.

[How to set value from firebase into TextFieldForm with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554341/how-to-set-value-from-firebase-into-textfieldform-with-flutter/61555235#61555235)

I have been stacked so long.
How can I get specified value from firestore with `DOCUMENT ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get data inside a document, then do the following:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document("docID").get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
});
```

`get()` will retrieve the data inside a document.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please let me know the document or sample of Firestore.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to add your document here `document("docID")`

Comment: I mean some samples or Firestore documents like these how to use. if you know.

Comment: check my post https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/

Comment: Thank you. Great article. I will check.